# Wordpress Let User Role "Author" edit/publish only pages ( not posts ) he is "Author" of

Tags: php, wordpress

simple question:

I have pages ( not posts ) on a website for the staff. So lets say a page with a profile for Mister Smith.

Now I made a new user with the role "author" and changed in the Wordpress editor the author of the page "Mister Smith Profile" to the user Mister Smith.

I want that if the user "Mister Smith" logs him self in into the wordpress wp-admin that he can only edit/publish his own page. And if possible that he only sees in the pages view his own pages.

It looks like that the wordrpess user roles only work for posts but not pages.

So I tried several plugins and either you need a charged pro version of the plugin or it is just nor possible.

`User role editor:` (https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) : Need the pro version.

`Role Scoper:` (https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/): You can still create new pages, see the other pages ( but get access denied if you want to edit them ), and you can delete all pages

`Press Permit Core` ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/press-permit-core/ ): Need pro Addon for like everything

`Capability Manager Enhanced:` ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/ ): You can still create new pages, see the other pages ( but get access denied if you want to edit them ), and you can delete all pages

I also tried the suggestion in this Thread:
[Limit WordPress user to edit only his own pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679040/limit-wordpress-user-to-edit-only-his-own-pages)

but it only worked for posts not pages !

So can anyone help me ?

Short version of my question:

User Role "Author" only edit/publish pages he is the author of. If possible with an plugin or maybe some coding on the wp functions.php.

Comment: This question should be on the WordPress Development SE site at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure about it, but I think if you use what you already linked to ([Limit WordPress user to edit only his own pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679040/limit-wordpress-user-to-edit-only-his-own-pages)) and use `edit_published_pages` ([see "Roles and Capabilites" from the WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_pages)) as the user capability, you might limit access to the page(s) that are designated to that user.

On the other hand: Why can´t you use posts? You can put them in a specific category, exclude that category from archives etc. pp. and it could all look like a page on the front.